# clearing a g-sheet content never finishes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Why is it that, when I run "clearAll()" the execution never finishes.

```
function clearAll() {
    clearRange('D4:D50');
    clearResults();
};

function clearResults() {
    clearRange('J3:ZZ913');    
};

function clearRange(rangeToClear) {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    const formulas = sheet.getRange(rangeToClear).getFormulas();

    sheet.getRange(rangeToClear).clear({
        contentsOnly: true,
        skipFilteredRows: false
    });
    sheet.getRange(rangeToClear).setFormulas(formulas)
};
```

Comment: What makes you think the execution never finishes?

Comment: You may see improved performance if you do the same thing but with the Sheets API.

Comment: @Diego can you please give an example? `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` is not the sheets API?

Comment: @EladBenda I left an example for you. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have better performance if you call the Sheets API in a more direct manner. The `SpreadsheetApp` class you're using is one of the "[Google Workspace services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)", which are generally easier to use than the APIs, but "are optimized for only the most common use cases."

I recommend using the [Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) for this. You'll need to authorize it, which is easy to do following the instructions in the previous link.

Unfortunately, I don't know of an equivalent to the [`getFormulas()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulas()) method, so you need to manually filter for them.

With the same range dimensions that you defined and every 15th row filled with the same simple formula, I was able to cut down the execution of `clearAll()` from 61 seconds to 7.3 seconds.

```
function clearAll() {
  clearRange('D4:D50');
  clearResults();
};

function clearResults() {
  clearRange('J3:ZZ913');    
};

function clearRange(rangeToClear) {
  rangeToClear = `Sheet1!${rangeToClear}`;
  const spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  const valueRange = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(
    spreadsheetId,
    rangeToClear,
    { valueRenderOption: 'FORMULA' }
  );
  
  const formulas = valueRange.values.map(function(row) {
    return row.map(function(cell) {
      if (cell.startsWith('=')) {
        return cell;
      }
      return '';
    });
  });
  
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(
    {
      majorDimension: 'ROWS',
      values: formulas
    },
    spreadsheetId,
    rangeToClear,
    { 'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED' }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### Issue:

You are trying to:

- get the formulas
- clear the values
- set the formulas back

in a range of **693** columns and **910** rows or in other words **630630** cells: `J3:ZZ913`.

This is a very intensive task which needs a lot of time to be executed. Note that, if the columns in the range `'J3:ZZ913'` don't exist the script will automatically create them for you which adds additional workload to the script. This is even more intensive if your file is already heavy and loaded with a lot of data.

There is no really a solution to this since it has to do with the [quotas for google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). You should restrict the range for which you want to apply the `clearRange` function or do this task in batches.

**FYI**, I tested your script and it managed to finish in time for an **empty** sheet. The more data you add in the specified range and generally in the sheet, the more time it requires for the script to finish. And hence you are approaching the script runtime quota.